# How can I paginate through Firebase Realtime db entries using MUI DataGrid?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, material-ui

the database entries have a key called 'date' whose value is a numerical date. The entries are ordered, and should be displayed in, descending chronological order (most recent first).

I've tried setting `cursor` to the least recent of the results and then using the `endBefore()` query filter when paginating right (through earlier entries) and the `startAfter()` query filter when paginating left (through more recent entries).

It seems to work fine when paginating through earlier entries, but when paginating back through the more recent entries, the current data shown either skips to the most recent (i.e back to page 0's data regardless of current page) if the pagination has been advanced by two or more pages, or doesn't change at all if it has been advanced by a single page. My code is below

```js
const PaginatedDataTable = () => {
    const [entryData, setEntryData] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [totalEntries, setTotalEntries] = useState(0);
    const [cursor, setCursor] = useState(Date.now());
    const [direction, setDirection] = useState("right");
    const [paginationModel, setPaginationModel] = useState({
      page: 0,
      pageSize: 5
    });
  
    React.useEffect(() => {
      onValue(query(ref(db, "/totalEntries")), (snapshot) => {
        setTotalEntries(snapshot.val());
      });
    }, []);
    // Some API clients return undefined while loading
    const [rowCountState, setRowCountState] = React.useState(totalEntries || 0);
    React.useEffect(() => {
      setRowCountState((prevRowCountState) => totalEntries ?? prevRowCountState);
    }, [totalEntries, setRowCountState]);
  

    React.useEffect(() => {
      setLoading(true);
      const entriesDataRef = ref(db, "/entries");
      onValue(
        query(
          entriesDataRef,
          orderByChild("date"),
          limitToLast(paginationModel.pageSize),
          direction === "right"
            ? endBefore(cursor)
            : startAfter(cursor)
        ),
        (snapshot) => {
          if (snapshot.val()) {
            setEntryData(Object.values(snapshot.val());
          }
          setLoading(false);
        }
      );
    }, [paginationModel]);
  

    const handlePaginationModelChange = (newPaginationModel) => {
      if (newPaginationModel.page > paginationModel.page) {
        // user clicked right (earlier entries), so we want endBefore
        setDirection("right");
        setCursor(entryData[0].date);
      } else {
        // user clicked left (more recent entries), so we want startAfter(?)
        setDirection("left");
        setCursor(newPaginationModel.page === 0 ? Date.now() : entryData[0].date);
      }
      setPaginationModel(newPaginationModel);
    };
  
  
    const rows = useCallback(
      () =>
        entryData.reverse().map((entry, i) => ({
          id: `entry-${i}`,
          date: entry.date,
          message: entry.message
        })),
      [entryData]
    );
  
    return (
      <DataGrid
        density="compact"
        rows={rows()}
        columns={columns()}
        pageSizeOptions={[5]}
        rowCount={rowCountState}
        paginationMode="server"
        onPaginationModelChange={handlePaginationModelChange}
        paginationModel={paginationModel}
        loading={loading}
      />
    );
  };
```

The calls to Firebase are as follows as I paginate through pages 0, 1, 2, 1, 0.

```
15:50:21.519 Testing.js:176 current cursor 1678549821501 (current time - to show most recent)
15:50:21.520 Testing.js:177 {page: 0, orderByChild: 'date', limitToLast: 5, endBefore: 1678549821501}

15:50:22.357 Testing.js:176 current cursor 1678487067312 (test message 12 - correct)
15:50:22.357 Testing.js:177 {page: 1, orderByChild: 'date', limitToLast: 5, endBefore: 1678487067312}

15:50:22.748 Testing.js:176 current cursor 1678487066809 (test message 7 - correct)
15:50:22.748 Testing.js:177 {page: 2, orderByChild: 'date', limitToLast: 5, endBefore: 1678487066809}

15:50:23.720 Testing.js:176 current cursor 1678487066306 (test message 2 - should be 12 I think)
15:50:23.720 Testing.js:177 {page: 1, orderByChild: 'date', limitToLast: 5, startAfter: 1678487066306}

15:50:24.310 Testing.js:176 current cursor 1678549824293 (current time - to show most recent)
15:50:24.310 Testing.js:177 {page: 0, orderByChild: 'date', limitToLast: 5, startAfter: 1678549824293}
```

The data in the database is structured as follows:

```json
{
    "-NQC1g3DobonwHZRo4MD": {
        "date": 1678477279517,
        "message": "test message"
    },
    "-NQCc0PylHPPugO8pd2v": {
        "date": 1678487066306,
        "message": "test message 2"
    },
    "-NQCc0RT5CiJqQzE2vDw": {
        "date": 1678487066402,
        "message": "test message 3"
    },
    "-NQCc0TCMmxlKxK2KSn3": {
        "date": 1678487066514,
        "message": "test message 4"
    },
    "-NQCc0Ugy5obKY8wF1se": {
        "date": 1678487066609,
        "message": "test message 5"
    },
    "-NQCc0WGyXANOq-5c3p2": {
        "date": 1678487066709,
        "message": "test message 6"
    },
    "-NQCc0XpWDyywv5G69XE": {
        "date": 1678487066809,
        "message": "test message 7"
    },
    "-NQCc0Z_DADlCPsXW-sW": {
        "date": 1678487066921,
        "message": "test message 8"
    },
    "-NQCc0a9xrkqRJI7HKE_": {
        "date": 1678487067022,
        "message": "test message 9"
    },
    "-NQCc0bel2esMOow5yzc": {
        "date": 1678487067119,
        "message": "test message 10"
    },
    "-NQCc0d9HFjkuSAe7Xhe": {
        "date": 1678487067215,
        "message": "test message 11"
    },
    "-NQCc0efaY4wqXHaoiTu": {
        "date": 1678487067312,
        "message": "test message 12"
    },
    "-NQCc0gW7Mtj5j2jnFYe": {
        "date": 1678487067430,
        "message": "test message 13"
    },
    "-NQCc0iFNDgzoN2K2-TC": {
        "date": 1678487067540,
        "message": "test message 14"
    },
    "-NQCc0jmzuxbvLfX8TPD": {
        "date": 1678487067638,
        "message": "test message 15"
    },
    "-NQDJ0c_4anjVfJCiy9A": {
        "date": 1678498601514,
        "message": "test message 16",
    }
}
```

What can be done to allow for pagination both ways? Is there a better way of achieving this then what I've tried?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: "inconsistent behaviour" and "it isn't really working" are really hard to help with. Can you show the exact call to the Firebase API that isn't working, with hard-coded values for all parameters?

Comment: I've updated the post with some more details. When paginating towards the most recent entries, the data from the Firebase query goes back to page 0's data if the pagination has advanced two or more pages, and doesn't change at all if less than two pages.

Comment: Hmmm.... shouldn't that 4th set of entries in the log output be an `endBefore`, since you're paginating backwards? I'd also expect your code to use `limitToFirst` for forward pagination, and `limitToLast` (only) for backwards pagination - which doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: I think so, but that's controlled by which pagination button the user has clicked, and I'm struggling to think of a better way of doing it. I'm afraid I'm not getting anywhere with this. I've just tried `limitToLast` only for backwards pagination and it just gives me the 5 latest entries, regardless of page, and paginating forwards (with `endBefore` and `limitToFirst`) towards the more recent entries now shows me the first 5 entries (ever)

Comment: The problem I have is that there's quite some complexity in your code, making it hard to help. The log output was helpful for finding that `limitToFirst`/`limitToLast` inversion, but no there seems to be another problem - and mentally stepping through your code line by line and imagining the updates you made is not really feasible (for me at least). If you can show the exact API call with the specific parameter values that you make to the Realtime Database that is giving unexpected results, it is much more likely that I (or someone else) spots what is going wrong.

Comment: It appears to be working fine by simply using `orderByChild('date')` with `limitToLast(pageSize * page)` (i.e, 5 results per page means 1 page = 5 results, 2 pages = 10 results...) and removing `paginationMode="server"` from `<DataGrid>`, so perhaps this is just a MUI problem. Thanks for trying to help and apologies if it was more complex than necessary.